device is not secure application terminated
I am trying to install one of my apk file in genymotion and iam receiving "device isn't secure, application terminated" this popup and the application is not running please help with the error message.

This is probably because Genymotion devices with Android 13 and lower are rooted.
You cannot unroot them, but if you have a paying license, you can use Android 14 which is not rooted (see Genymotion Desktop user guide).
